# How to prevent JavaFX Menu gap until resize?

Tags: java, javafx, ubuntu-14.04

JavaFX MenuBar has a large gap between it and any Menus until a resize is performed.
After resize, the Menus sit flush against the MenuBar as expected. Assuming this is not widespread behavior because a search doesn't turn anything up (or I'm searching the wrong terms).

Java: 1.8.0_20

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Before resize:

[image: Before resize]

After resize:

[image: After Resize]

Any ideas on how to get consistent behaviour here?

Code used to make the screenshots:

```
public class DemoFX extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
      root.setPrefSize(400, 400);

      Menu a = new Menu("A");
      a.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("A1"), new MenuItem("A2"));

      MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
      bar.getMenus().add(a);
      root.setTop(bar);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: This issue does not reproduce on Win7 Java8u20.  The issue looks similar to [RT-28775 PopupWindow with content with Shadow Effect, wrong position](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28775), but that was marked as fixed for Lombard (which was the codename for the initial JavaFX for Java 8 release).  Perhaps there is a lingering issue around Linux rendering which was not addressed.  I suggest you file a (new) bug report in the linked issue tracker.

Comment: Follow up: my ticket was closed as 'unable to reproduce'. I guess I'll just live with it.

Comment: Another update: going with a non-default font size also solves it.